# Is there a way to write vba for Sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint

Hi guys I haven’t got a clue where to start what I’m after is I have 5 excel workbooks loaded onto Sharepoint these all have different people that can access them . Now each workbook has 3 sheets on them what I’m after is a master excel workbook that only has 1 sheet on it called master data that gets only 1 sheet from each workbook called holidays,sickness,request,overtime,jobs and copies them and puts them underneath one another on the sheet and always updates . The sheets I need copying all have same number of rows and columns but I need to keep the same formatting and variables . Or is there a way where on Sharepoint I can link just that 1 sheet on each and put it into the master.

I tried doing this by auto record macro but it didn’t work .

Answer (score 0):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/vba-differences

And: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133197/excel-vba-code-to-upload-document-into-sharepoint-online-2013

Is there a specific need to use VBA? I would suggest to use PowerAutomate or PowerQuery: https://macrordinary.ca/2020/07/13/where-does-vba-fit-in-2020/

If you absolutely need to use VBA here is a script to get you started based on the source above:

```
Sub CopySheetsFromSharePoint()
    Dim SourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim TargetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim SharePointURL As String
    Dim FileURL As String

    SharePointURL = "https://SharePointSiteURL/"

    FileURL = SharePointURL & "FilePath/FileName.xlsx"

    Set SourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FileURL)

    Set TargetWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

    SourceWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Copy After:=TargetWorkbook.Sheets(TargetWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

    SourceWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

I highly recommend you use PowerAutomate which better integrates with the O365 ecosystem.

Comment: Hi where do I get the filepath/ file name from and also I tried automate but it wouldn’t copy and paste new changes that was made in the original sheet